# How to remove an image from Nuke for Swift cache

Tags: ios, swift, image-caching

I have been trying out Nuke framework for Image caching, from https://github.com/kean/Nuke, across the document I couldn't figure out how to remove an image from cache (both disk and memory), I could find a method from Cache class "removeAll" to remove images from cache , but I have two questions:

1. How to remove single image?
2. How to remove all images from disk as well as memory cache?

I haven't tried anything I am trying to check the documents before trying , so down voting because I don't have attached code isn't fare.

Comment: If you are pretty sure that there is no documentation about this issue, I would suggest to report it as an issue on the github repo.

Comment: https://github.com/kean/Nuke/issues/128

Comment: So eventually they allow us manipulate Cache through URLCache but its not straight , not good for a framework

Answer (score 2):

To store unprocessed image data, Nuke uses a `URLCache` instance. So you have to call `removeAllCachedResponses()` of an appropriate `URLCache` instance.

As a result, you can clear image stored in disk as below codes if you use the shared instance of Nuke as mentioned by Sergey Di on [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169524/how-to-remove-an-image-from-nuke-for-swift-cache#comment77308970_45169524)

```
Nuke.Cache.shared.removeAll()
Nuke.DataLoader.sharedUrlCache.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

If you use a custom shared ImagePipeline, it's a bit complicated but you can do like this code

```
(ImagePipeline.shared.configuration.dataLoader as? DataLoader)?.session.configuration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

I hope my answer would help you.

Comment: It gives me an error: Module 'Nuke' has no member named 'Cache'

Comment: @Ramis Try Nuke.ImageCache